# Vue elements not hiding with v-show

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Im under the assumption that v-show will show/hide elements based on its passed data.

For some reason, my element will not hide dynamically when v-show is false. When I manually change the variable (showNav) to false, it will be hidden on page load so it seems to functioning properly.

My variable (showNav) depends on scroll. When scroll up, it is set to true, when scroll down it is set to false. I'd like my nav bar to hide on scroll down but that is not happening.

The scroll behavior is behaving properly. Both are properly changing my v-show variable (showNav) to either true or false but the element remains visible at all times.

HTML template

```
<template>
    <div id="home-page">
            <Navbar id="navbar" v-show="showNav" :class="{change_background: scrollPosition > 50}" />
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
mounted() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
              // detects new state and compares it with the old one
              if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > this.scrollPos) {
                this.showNav = true;
                console.log(this.showNav);
              }
              else
              {
                this.showNav = false;
                console.log(this.showNav);
              }
              // saves the new position for iteration.
              this.scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
            })
        },
        data() {
            return {
                scrollPosition: null,
                scrollPos: 0,
                showNav: true,
            }
        },
```

Comment: quick solution: just change the callback you pass in "scroll" event handler from regular to arrow function. Then the key word "this" will behave correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the `scroll` events by binding one of the methods defined within the `methods` block to the scroll event of the window. In your case the `callback` function passed to the `scroll` event listen will not have access to the `vue instance` and hence it will not update the reactive properties of `vuejs`. See the working sample below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      scrollPosition: null,
      scrollPos: 0,
      showNav: true,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll); // To avoid memory leakage
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
      // detects new state and compares it with the old one
      if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > this.scrollPos) {
        this.showNav = true;
        console.log(this.showNav);
      } else {
        this.showNav = false;
        console.log(this.showNav);
      }
      // saves the new position for iteration.
      this.scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" style="min-height: 1000px;">
  <span v-show="showNav">You are trying to hide me</span>
</div>
```