# Vuejs v-for so laggy when infinite scrolling

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this weird vuejs effect where when I am adding a new object data, the v-for re-renders all the object even if its already rendered.

I am implementing an infinite scroll like facebook.

### The Code

To explain this code, I am fetching a new data from firebase and then push the data into the data object when it reaches the bottom of the screen

```js
var vueApp = new Vue({

    el: '#root',
    data: {
        postList: [],
        isOkaytoLoad: false,
        isRoomPostEmpty: false,
    },
    mounted: function() {
        // Everytime user scroll, call handleScroll() method
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },
    methods: {
        handleScroll: function()
        {
            var d = document.documentElement;
            var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
            var height = d.offsetHeight - 200;
            
            // If the user is near the bottom and it's okay to load new data, get new data from firebase
            if (this.isOkaytoLoad && offset >= height)
            {
                this.isOkaytoLoad = false;
                (async()=>{
                    const lastPost = this.postList[this.postList.length - 1];
                    const room_id = PARAMETERS.get('room');

                    const q = query(collection(db, 'posts'), where('room', '==', room_id), orderBy("time", "desc"), limit(5), startAfter(lastPost));
                    const roomSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                    roomSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        const postID = doc.id;
                        (async()=>{
                            // Put the new data at the postList object
                            this.postList = [...this.postList, doc];
                            const q = query(collection(db, 'comments'), where('post_id', '==', postID));
                            const commentSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                            doc['commentCount'] = commentSnapshot.size;
                            //this.postList.push(doc);
                            console.log(this.postList);
                            setTimeout(()=>{ this.isOkaytoLoad = true }, 1000);
                        })();
                    });
                    
                    
                })();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div v-if="postList.length > 0" class="card-containers">
   <!-- I have a component `Postcard` in my js file and it works well -->
   <Postcard 
      v-for="post in postList" 
      :key="post.id" 
      :post-id="post.id" 
      :owner-name="post.data().owner_displayName" 
      :owner-uid="post.data().owner_id" 
      :post-type="post.data().post_type"
      :image-url="post.data().image_url"
      :post-content="truncateString(linkify(post.data().post_content))"
      :room="post.data().room" 
      :time="post.data().time.toDate()"
      :likers="post.data().likers"
      :comment-count="post.commentCount"
      :file-url="post.data().file_url"
      :file-name="post.data().file_name"
      :downloads="post.data().downloads">
   </Postcard>
</div>
```

### Now, the problem is here ...

Look at this screen record, **FOCUS AT THE MOUSE**, it's lagging and I can't even click on those buttons when vuejs is adding and loading the new data

[image: I can't click when new data is loading]

Here is the code That I used

### What I suspect

I am suspecting that everytime I add a new data, the VueJS re-renders it all, which does that effect. How can I force vueJS to not re-render those data that is already rendered in the screen?

Comment: are you using virtual scrolling ?

Comment: Could you post the code (simplified) of `Postcard` component?

Comment: Why are you updating `postList` twice? First with -> `this.postList = [...this.postList, doc];` and then after few lines `this.postList.push(doc);` ?

Comment: Why do you have two async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)? That second one especially in the `forEach` will *kill* performance because it will update each doc independently, instead of batching all the updates together at the end.

Comment: @Ayudh no, could you send me a good resource about virtual scrolling?

Comment: @saibbyweb I have now edited it, i commented the .push() method because it's for my debugging purposes

Comment: @DecadeMoon the first async is for the roomSnapshot ```await getDocs(q)``` and the second async is for the commentSnapshot ```await getDocs(q)```. I dont know but the second await does not work even if its already inside an async function so I decided to wrap it in another async()

Comment: It's worth mentioning that since you've used scroll handler, please use the `unmounted` or `beforeDestroy` hooks to unbind the scroll handler to avoid memory leaks. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969394/vue-elements-not-hiding-with-v-show/69969462#69969462)

Comment: @Salvino thanks for that information

Comment: google virtual scrolling and see if you can find any vue library that supports it. I've found many results for it. That'll help your performance significantly

Answer (score 1):

You've got two unnecessary async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE); the second one inside the `forEach` is particularly problematic because the async code inside it will be executed concurrently for each loop iteration, which has implications:

1. `getDocs()` will be fired all at once for each loop ieration, potentially spamming the server (assuming this is performing a network request). Was this your intention? It looks like you're only fetching at most 5 new posts, so this is probably OK.
2. The async function updates some state which will trigger Vue to re-render for each doc. This should be batched together at the end so Vue does as minimal updates as possible.

Also don't use `var`; use `const` or `let` instead. There's almost no good reason to use `var` anymore, let it die.

I can't say this will improve your performance substantially, but I recommend making the following changes (untested):

```js
async handleScroll() {
  const d = document.documentElement;
  const offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
  const height = d.offsetHeight - 200;
  
  // If the user is near the bottom and it's okay to load new data, get new data from firebase
  if (this.isOkaytoLoad && offset >= height) {
    // Prevent loading while we load more posts
    this.isOkaytoLoad = false;

    try {
      // Get new posts
      const lastPost = this.postList[this.postList.length - 1];
      const room_id = PARAMETERS.get('room');
      const q = query(collection(db, 'posts'), where('room', '==', room_id), orderBy("time", "desc"), limit(5), startAfter(lastPost));
      const roomSnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      // Fetch comments of each post. Do this all at once for each post.
      // TODO: This can probably be optimized into a single query
      // for all the posts, instead of one query per post.
      await Promise.all(roomSnapshot.docs.map(async doc => {
        const postID = doc.id;
        const q = query(collection(db, 'comments'), where('post_id', '==', postID));
        const commentSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        doc.commentCount = commentSnapshot.size;
      }));

      // Append the new posts to the list
      this.postList.push(...roomSnapshot.docs);
    } catch (ex) {
      // TODO: Handle error
    } finally {
      // Wait a bit to re-enable loading
      setTimeout(() => { this.isOkaytoLoad = true }, 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Doing `:post-content="truncateString(linkify(post.data().post_content))"` in the template means `linkify` will be executed during each re-render. I suspect `linkify` may be potentially slow for long lists? Can this be pre-calculated for each post ahead of time?

You're registering a window scroll event listener when the component is mounted. If the component is ever destroyed, you need to unregister the event listener otherwise it'll still fire whenever the window is scrolled. This may not be an issue in your case, but for reusable components it must be done.

Comment: Update: I did manage work with this, but it still does the weird mouse thing shown above